# Pair wise disjoint open balls

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,ρ)$ be a metric space and $A$ is a subset of $X$. How do I prove that there exists a family $(B(t,r_{t}))_{t\in\operatorname{Iso}A}$ of pair wise disjoint open balls?

Comment: What is $IsoA$?

Comment: Set of isolated points of A

Comment: Why do you think that such a family exists?

Comment: came across it in a examination paper

Comment: You should include that context in the question - what exam was it? What level is it at? That will help others make their answers more focused, and help others who look at the question in the future.

Comment: 3rd year Topology examination

Comment: @Rajinda Wickrama: I am sure this is not your intention, but it might appear as if you are being evasive about which exam you are looking at. Do you not know the institution and the year the exam was given?

Answer (score 4):

Recall that a point $t \in A$ is isolated in $A$ if there is some ball $B(t, r_t)$ centered at $t$ of radius $r_t > 0$ which does not meet any other point of $A$. Now consider the family $\{B(t, r_t/10) : t \in \text{Iso}(A)\}$.

Proof: Suppose $x \in B(t_1, r_1/10) \cap B(t_2, r_2/10)$. WLOG, $r_1 \leq r_2$. But then $t_1 \in B(t_2, r_2)$!.

Comment: It's very non-obvious why $r_t/10$ works for any choice of $r_t$.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't. That was careless.

Comment: @AsafKaragila what if we take $r_{t}=dist(t,A)/2$

Comment: @Rajinda: $t\in A$ so $d(t,A)=0$. But even if it weren't (e.g. take $d(t,A')$ instead), there's no guarantee that the balls are pairwise disjoint. You need a better argument. E.g. one appealing to paracompactness for example, or regularity/normality of metric spaces.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I suppose  t∈IsoA implies dist(t,A)>0

Comment: @Rajinda: If $t$ is an isolated point of $A$, in particular $t$ is a member of $A$, therefore $d(t,A)=0$.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake

Comment: I added a (very simple) proof.